# How to elegantly query for a record and create it if it does not exist yet?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

### The Goal

The goal of `startChat(partner_profile)` is to get the id of a chat between two users to then be able to redirect to this chat. 
There are **two different cases**:

1. a chat between them already exists

   a) `partner_profile` is first participant

   b) `partner_profile` is second participant
2. the chat between them needs to be created first

### What I got so far

I know how to get an ID for each of the above listed cases, but I do not know how to combine them all. Here is my code so far:

```js
 startChat(partner_profile) {
      // case 1a
      this.get('store').queryRecord('chat', {
              first_participant: partner_profile.id
       }).then(function(chat) {
              let id = chat.get('id');
              onSaveSuccess(id);
       }).catch(function(){
      });

      // case 1b
     this.get('store').queryRecord('chat', {
             second_participant: partner_profile.id
     }).then(function(chat) {
            let id = chat.get('id');
            onSaveSuccess(id);
            return;
     }).catch(function(){
         // **error handling* 
    });

    // case 2
    let chat = this.get('store').createRecord('chat', {
        second_participant: partner_profile
    });

    let onSaveSuccess = (id) => this.transitionToRoute('chats.chat',id);

    chat.save()
        .then(function(success) {
            let id = success.get('id');
            onSaveSuccess(id);
         })
        .catch((error) => {
           // **error handling*
      }
    });
```

### How can I combine those cases?

Right now it's really ugly, because every case is executed and of course two of them fail. How could I do this in a nicer way? Is there a way to `get_or_create` a record at once (like there is in Django)?
Thank you for your help :-)

### Edit: more specific

To be more specific, I have a problem to find a good way to check whether the chat already exists in our database. See this example:

```
   let existingChat =  this.get('store').queryRecord('chat', {
      first_participant: partner_profile.id
  }).catch(function(){

   });
  if(!existingChat){
    // ** check for case 1b and 2
  };
```

In this example I first query the store for the chat. The store returns a Promise which I saved in `existingChat` and that is not resolved yet when I want to check whether a chat already exists with `if(!existingChat)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the best way to do this is to first query for that chat, and then handle creating the chat if it isn't found (a 404):

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  // params is { first_participant, second_participant }
  model(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('chat', params)
      .catch(() => {
        // a 404 from the server would trigger a catch
        return this.store.createRecord('chat', params);
      });
  }
});
```

Basically that's the concept, but it can be more involved if you need to create two chats. In that case you can use the `all` or `hash` helpers from 'rsvp'.

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { hash } from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend({
  // params is { first_participant, second_participant }
  model(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('chat', params)
      .catch(() => {
        // a 404 from the server would trigger a catch
        return hash({
          chatA: this.store.createRecord('chat', { first_participant: params.first_participant }),
          chatB: this.store.createRecord('chat', { second_participant: params.second_participant })
        });
      });
  }
});
```

The above would set your `model` as `{ chatA, chatB }`. The complexity of what you need to do with your promises also depends on how complicated your backend API is. Sometimes this is a smell letting you know that your API isn't the best that it could be.

---

Another solution, which is more elegant, is to use async/await.
Check out this guide: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/29/async-await-ember-project/

Async/await is ready for prime time IMO. The example above would look like so:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  // params is { first_participant, second_participant }
  async model(params) {
    let chat;

    try {
      chat = await this.store.queryRecord('chat', params);
    } catch(e) {
      // a 404 from the server would trigger a catch
      chat = await this.store.createRecord('chat', params);
    }

    return chat;
  }
});
```

This allows you to write async code in a sync manner, making it easier to write and understand.

To start using the above, you'd need to modify your `ember-cli-build.js` file like the blog post above specifies, i.e.

```
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  // Add options here
  babel: {
    includePolyfill: true
  }
});
```

For more details I recommend this in-depth article http://rwjblue.com/2017/10/30/async-await-configuration-adventure/

Comment: I do not need to create two different chats. I only need to query for the existing chat in two different ways (because the chat partner could be saved as `first_participant` or `second_participant`). You are right that the API is a little cumbersome here, but I inherited this code and it would take too much time to change it right now.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me! Now I have nicely structured code!

Comment: @Whiterose I've updated my answer to add another more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you for your update! I just saw it, sorry for the delay. I stumbled upon `await` while researching for the answer and did not use it because it is not officially supported yet in Ember if I understood it correctly. Also I need to be able to support older browsers (in the in-depth article you provided it is stated that only the last two versions of the popular browsers are supported as of October '17). But it makes me hopefull that in the future we won't need such ugly then-catch-chains anymore ^^

Comment: With the babelPolyfill, you don't have to worry about browser compatibility because it changes the code to a format that all current browsers support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have enough of your code, but here is how I have handled  `get_or_create` in the past.

```js
var database = [];

function getOrCreate(rowId) {
  var rowIndex = database.findIndex(r => rowId === r.Id);  
  if (rowIndex < 0) {
    database.push({
      Id: rowId
    });
    return database[database.length - 1];
  } else {
    return database[rowIndex];
  }
}

var item1 = getOrCreate(1);
var item2 = getOrCreate(2);
var item3 = getOrCreate(3);
var item4 = getOrCreate(1);

console.log(item4);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly, your answer does not help me, but this is on me. I should have been more specific in describing my problem. I do not know what I could insert in the if (the check for whether the object already exists). The Ember store returns a Promise, so `let existingChat =  this.get('store').queryRecord(...) if(!existingChat)` does not work. I will expand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code reorganized according to @knownasilya's suggestion:

```
getChatFirstParticipant().then(transitionToChat)
    .catch(() => {
      getChatSecondParticipant().then(transitionToChat)
         .catch(() => {
           createChat(partner_profile).then(transitionToChat)
             .catch((error) => {
               // ** error handling** 
             });
     });
```